# Scrapy Extracting text based on a specific pattern in the class

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I am trying to extract information based on a specific pattern in the HTML code. Ideally, I would like to extract the text for the div class that mentions "bg-deep-green" only. I am new to regular expressions so I wasn't sure if there is a way to use them or any other method via xpath.

Here is a sample of the HTML:

```
<div class="flex flex-row w-full mb-lg">
     <div class="flex text-center text-sm text-white rounded-l-full bg-green">&lt; 30</div>
     <div class="flex text-center text-sm text-white bg-green">30 - 78</div>
     <div class="flex text-center text-sm text-white rounded-r-full bg-deep-green">&gt; 78</div></div>
```

I have the xpath for the parent that scrapes all of the tags.

`response.xpath('//*[@class="flex flex-row w-full mb-lg"]//@class').extract()`

Also, the xpath that scrapes all of the text for the tags.

`response.xpath('//*[@class="flex flex-row w-full mb-lg"]//text()').extract()`

Worst case scenario I could parse it out after the scrape, I think, but it would be nice if I could do it before the scrape.

I have tried using `contains` in various ways and by using the `string` notation in the documentation. Below are a few of my tries, however, I may be misunderstanding contains from the documentation.

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="flex flex-row w-full mb-lg"]/div/[contains("bg-deep-green")]/text()')

response.xpath('//*[@class="flex flex-row w-full mb-lg"]/div/[contains(., "bg-deep-green")]')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be enough

```
response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'bg-deep-green')]/text()").extract()[0].strip()
```

Output

```
'> 78'
```

Comment: Well that was a lot easier than I expected. Thanks for informing me about that functionality.

Comment: you got it ...!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for XPath Expression is wrong, it should be like this:

```
response.xpath("//div[@class='flex flex-row w-full mb-lg']/div[contains(@class , 'bg-deep-green")]/text()')
```

OR You can Just Use:

```
response.xpath("//div[contains(@class , 'bg-deep-green')]/text()")
```